# Using switch in typescript with if statement

Tags: typescript

what I did wrong in my code that when I'm calling the function on case 2, the output comes from case 3.
can I use the if inside the switch?
I want that the code not enter to the third case, in this calling.

```js
CheckInputErrMess(2,10);


function CheckInputErrMess(stepToCheck: number, numToCheck: any): number {
    let message: string = "";
    let error: number = 0;

    switch (stepToCheck) {
        case 1:

            if (numToCheck != 1 && numToCheck != 2 && numToCheck != 3 || isNaN(numToCheck)) {
                message = "Error. Please select 1 or 2 or 3, for the shape type. <br>";
                document.write(message);
                error = 1;
                return error;
            }
        case 2:

            if (numToCheck <= 0 || (Math.ceil(numToCheck) - numToCheck) > 0 || isNaN(numToCheck)) { 
                message = "Error. Please enter a positive integer number. <br>" ;
                document.write(message);
                error = 2;
                return error;  
            }

        case 3:

            if (numToCheck != 1 && numToCheck != 2 && numToCheck != 3 && numToCheck != 4 || isNaN(numToCheck)) {
                message = "Error. Please select 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, for the shape content. <br>";
                document.write(message);
                error = 3;
                return error;
            }

        }

    return error;

    }
```

Comment: you still may remove this question to avoid its negative rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript's switch statements allow fallthrough; once a `case` condition is matched, the following `case`s are executed too.

You can disable this behaviour in the tsc compilation settings but a more sensible solution is to explicitly `break` after each case:

```js
function mySwitchWithIfs(a: number, b: number): number {
    
  switch (a) {
    case 1:
      if (/* ... */) {
        // ...
      }
      break;
      
    case 2:
      if (/* ... */) {
        // ...
      }
      break;
      
    ...
  }
}

mySwitchWithIfs(1, 100);
```

(If you do decide to disable fallthrough, the tsc compilation option is [noFallthroughCasesInSwitch](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noFallthroughCasesInSwitch).)